# Android: A text keyboard pops up on Focus change of EditText to Button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText with input type of number. It subscribes to the OnFocusChangeListener event. It shows the usual number pad on clicking. When I change my focus from this EditText to a Button next to it, it automatically pops up a text keyboard. Is this some common bug in the android or some code error?

When the number pad is minimized, this doesn't happen.
I have no other text box in the layout, just one EditText and few buttons, so it doesn't seem like a code error.

My application min SDK version is 14 and target is 22.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the focus change listener updates an object. It has the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if (!hasFocus)
        {
            Model cm = (Model) ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).getTag();

            cm.setWidth(Integer.parseInt(((EditText) v).getEditableText().toString()));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does the listener do?

Comment: @karaokyo The listener updates an object and call notifyDataSetChanged(). And all of it is in a custom list adapter